# Unpacking a PKCS7 payload from an iOS device (MDM enrollment)

Tags: ios, node.js, openssl

I'm trying to build a MDM server, given ruby code by Apple is :

```
p7sign = OpenSSL::PKCS7::PKCS7.new(req.body)
store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
p7sign.verify(nil, store, nil, OpenSSL::PKCS7::NOVERIFY)
signers = p7sign.signers
```

I have this very basic NodeJS code to receive & store the POST payload :

```
exports.profile = function(req, res) {
    var queryData = "";
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        queryData += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
        fs.writeFileSync('out.p7s', queryData);
    });
    res.send('1');
};
```

However the given file : https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2310128/ios-mdm.p7s

Can't seems to be recognized by openssl at all!!

```
openssl pkcs7 -in req.p7s -inform DER -print_certs
```

Is returning :

```
unable to load PKCS7 object
140735186985436:error:0D07207B:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_get_object:header too long:asn1_lib.c:150:
```

Any idea what could go wrong here? Is there some extra padding I should remove? Is the given file not PKCS7 at all?

Request headers :

```
{ host: '192.168.22.39:3000',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'content-type': 'application/pkcs7-signature',
  'accept-language': 'fr-fr',
  cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3Andcjz5pGCdb1AYXhNG8Us5mh.5szK2X1cOpnih9X5kCbqTUdpv8EyJRwNHl4VC6M5Gwk',
  accept: '*/*',
  'content-length': '3564',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'user-agent': 'Profile/1.0' }
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use `Buffer.concat` to correctly append binary buffers & make it work.

Comment: So what did your final code end up looking like?  I'm using Buffer.concat in my middleware to get req.rawBody as binary buffer. I'm running into the same issue you had before.

Answer (score 0):

The file you shared has no end of line characters. I'm not a NodeJS expert, but it looks like you are not saving the file as a binary file.  Can you try making the following change to see if this works?

```
req.on('end', function() {
    fs.writeFileSync('out.p7s', queryData, 'binary');
});
```

Comment: Did not work, I'm trying to use Buffer concatenation, maybe strings are somehow breaking the binary data.

Comment: @Olivier Not sure if this will help, but here is a valid pkcs7 file I saved during an MDM enrollment: [ota-response.p7s](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/wc6mifwx8v4rxoy/ota-response.p7s)